# Android kSOAP2: Namespace inexplicably added within XML parameter on server side

Tags: java, android, xml, web-services, ksoap2

I'm trying to send some XML as a parameter within a SOAP request from an Android app I'm developing. The problem is that despite the fact that the request dump looks to be exactly what I require, it appears that the namespace for the upper-level method is being added into one of the inner tags of the XML parameter when the request is received on the server side:

The Java code:

```
public String uploadOpRecordsV2(Cursor op) throws IOException {
    SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = null;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = null;
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = null;

    try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("[website url]", "UploadOpRecordsV2");
        request.addProperty("username", sharedprefs.getString("Username", "none"));
        request.addProperty("password", "sharedprefs.getString("Password", "none")");
        request.addProperty("clientid", sharedprefs.getString("ClientID", "none"));
        SoapObject records = new SoapObject("", "records");
        SoapObject newRecords = new SoapObject("", "NewRecords");

        LocalDBHandler database = LocalDBHandler.getInstance(context);
        op = db.getEntireTable("thin_client_operations");
        op.moveToFirst();

        while (!op.isAfterLast()) {
            SoapObject db = new SoapObject("", "db");
            db.addAttribute("type", 1);
            db.addProperty("ID", database.getStringColumnValueNoClose(op, "id"));
            db.addProperty("PA", database.getStringColumnValueNoClose(op, "patientage"));
            db.addProperty("SP", sharedprefs.getString("Specialty", "none"));
            db.addProperty("OD", database.getStringColumnValueNoClose(op, "operationdate"));
            db.addProperty("HN", Validation.decrypt(database.getStringColumnValueNoClose(op, "hospitalnumber")));
            db.addProperty("PV", (database.getIntColumnValueNoClose(op, "id") == 1));
            db.addProperty("BT", "");
            db.addProperty("AG", database.getStringColumnValueNoClose(op, "asagrade"));
            db.addProperty("OC", database.getStringColumnValueNoClose(op, "operationcode"));
            db.addProperty("HC", database.getStringColumnValueNoClose(op, "hospitalcode"));
            db.addProperty("CO", "6130249");
            db.addProperty("SU", database.getStringColumnValueNoClose(op, "supervision"));
            db.addProperty("CE", database.getStringColumnValueNoClose(op, "cepod"));
            db.addProperty("NT", database.getStringColumnValueNoClose(op, "notes"));
            db.addProperty("CM", "Complications");
            db.addProperty("CP", "False");

            newRecords.addSoapObject(db);
            op.moveToNext();
        }
        records.addSoapObject(newRecords);
        request.addSoapObject(records);
        request.addProperty("src", "rcsedApp");
        op.close();

        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        envelope.xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("[webservice url]");
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call("[websiteurl/UploadOpRecordsV2]", envelope);
        resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

        Log.e("Request", androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
        Log.e("Response", androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
        return androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
    }

    catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The log from the request dump, everything appears fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <UploadOpRecordsV2 xmlns="[websiteurl]">
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
      <clientid>string</clientid>
      <records>
        <NewRecords>
            <db type="1">
                <ID>df8aaba5-5784-42dc-93a7-b37f50610e38</ID>
                <PA>28</PA>
                <SP>CardiacSur</SP>
                <OD>08/07/2014 00:00:00</OD>
                <HN>23456</HN>
                <PV>false</PV>
                <BT></BT>
                <AG>2</AG>
                <OC>139</OC>
                <HC>160</HC>
                <CO>6130249</CO>
                <SU>4</SU>
                <CE>1</CE>
                <NT></NT>
                <CM>Complications</CM>
                <CP>False</CP></db>
            </db>
        </NewRecords>
        </records>
      <src>srcname</src>
    </UploadOpRecordsV2>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The XML section of the request received by the server, sent to me by the technicians for the website:

```
NewRecords  <db type="1" xmlns="[websiteurl]"><ID>df8aaba5-5784-42dc-93a7-b37f50610e38</ID>
<PA>28</PA><SP>CardiacSur</SP><OD>08/07/2014 00:00:00</OD><HN>23456</HN>
<PV>false</PV><BT></BT><AG>2</AG><OC>139</OC><HC>160</HC><CO>6130249</CO>
<SU>4</SU><CE>1</CE><NT></NT><CM>Complications</CM><CP>False</CP></db>
```

Is it even possible for me to stop the namespace appearing in the db tag on the server side and if so how would I go about it? All the other posters with this problem solved it by setting "" as the namespace but it won't work here...

Any help would be massively appreciated.